# Azure Durable Function Return a Don't know how to bind to String. (Parameter 'value') Error in portal

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

Little bit new to azure durable function. I am trying out fanout/fanin Concept within the azure function.

```
    [FunctionName("MasterListUpdate")]
    public async Task<List<Task<string>>> RunOrchestrator(
   [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
    {
        var outputs = new List<Task<string>>();
              
        var datalist = context.GetInput<List<string>>();
      
        foreach (var state in StateList.States)
        {            
          
            outputs.Add(context.CallActivityAsync<string>("UpdatingTheDataSet", state));
        }          
        await Task.WhenAll(outputs.ToArray());         
        return outputs.ToList();
    }

    [FunctionName("UpdatingTheDataSet")]
    public async Task<string> AddData([ActivityTrigger]string state,ILogger log)
    {
               
       await _insertingAllData.UpdatingReleventData(state, log);       
        return state;           
    }


    [FunctionName("DurableFunctionStart")]
    public async Task HttpStart(
         [TimerTrigger("0 */60 * * * *"
        #if DEBUG
                    ,RunOnStartup =true
        #endif
        )]
    TimerInfo myTimer,

        [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient starter,
        ILogger log)
    {
        // Function input comes from the request content.
        string instanceId = await starter.StartNewAsync("MasterListUpdate", StateList.States);
        log.LogInformation($"Started orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'.");           
    }
```

try to trigger a timer function Using azure durable function.Locally this work fine. When try to host in azure portal

[image]

it throw a error like this. Could not able to find out where I am doing wrong here.

** Note:-  StateList.States this is a static list.
Locally this work fine**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We tried to reproduced the same scenario and its working fine.

Here you are facing the issue and it may be cause for the error.

```cs
await _insertingAllData.UpdatingReleventData(state, log);
```

So, rewriting this code as below example and it's working as expected.

**Example Code :-**

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace DuralbeFunction
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("RunOrchestrator")]
        public static async Task<List<Task<string>>> RunOrchestrator(
            [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
        {
            var stateList = new List<StateList>()
            {
                new StateList(){State="Delhi"},
                new StateList(){State="UP"},
                new StateList(){State="Goa"},
            };
 
            var outputs = new List<Task<string>>();
            var datalist = context.GetInput<List<string>>();
            foreach (var state in stateList)
            {
                outputs.Add(context.CallActivityAsync<string>("Activity_Function1_Hello", state.State));
            }
            await Task.WhenAll(outputs.ToArray());
            return outputs.ToList();
        }
        
        [FunctionName("Activity_Function1_Hello")]
        public static string SayHello([ActivityTrigger] string name, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"Saying hello to {name}.");
            return $"Hello {name}!";
        }

        [FunctionName("Function1_HttpStart")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> HttpStart(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestMessage req,
            [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient starter,
            ILogger log)
        {
            string instanceId = await starter.StartNewAsync("RunOrchestrator", null);
            log.LogInformation($"Started orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'.");
            return starter.CreateCheckStatusResponse(req, instanceId);
        }    
    }
    public class StateList
    {
        public string State { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Output : -**

[image]

**Kudo output :-**
[image]

Comment: What you've changed? Why does it work for you? You should add some explanation to your answer and not just throw some code...

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same cryptic error message along with a FunctionInvocationException (related to the Orchestrator) when trying to invoke the Orchestrator function from the Azure portal (in my case, I as testing it through the Code + Test section).

After lots of researching, I found out invoking the Orchestrator through the Azure portal [is not allowed](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/issues/270). Invoking it through a tool like Postman worked without any issues. I hope this saves others some time.